# Projecting a function between two vectors, into a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

The distance coefficient in `R` between two vectors `X`,`Y` can be calculated with the `dcor(X,Y)` function of `energy` package. I have a matrix `Z` like this

```r
library(energy)

Z <- data.frame(Z1 = c(0.2, 3, 0.01, 3.4, 6),
                Z2 = c(2.2, 3.5, 0.5, 0.3, 7.0),
                Z3 = c(4.7, 0.003, 1.4, 0, 0.6))
```

and I want to create the distance correlation matrix for all combinations. How can I create a function that does this calculation? The final result must look like this

```
     Z1     Z2     Z3
Z1   1      0.76   0.76
Z2   0.76   1      0.48
Z3   0.76   0.48   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems that `energy::dcor` cannot do cross computation on a single dataframe like `stats::cor`. A workaround is using `outer`:

```r
outer(Z, Z, Vectorize(energy::dcor))

#           Z1        Z2        Z3
# Z1 1.0000000 0.7632896 0.7647835
# Z2 0.7632896 1.0000000 0.4783923
# Z3 0.7647835 0.4783923 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `combn` to calculate only needed pairwise combinations and then convert to `matrix` - thus, we don't have to redo the same calculations

```
library(energy)
v1 <- combn(Z, 2, FUN = \(x) dcor(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
as.matrix(as.dist(c(0, v1)))[-1, -1]
        2         3         4
2 0.0000000 0.7632896 0.7647835
3 0.7632896 0.0000000 0.4783923
4 0.7647835 0.4783923 0.0000000
```